# What's the best way to create a RxJS Observable out of objects that are yielded from a node.js stream pipeline?

Tags: node.js, rxjs

I was able to implement this, but I'm not able to explain why the process will exit with code 0 if I don't have another async function (`processAfterDeclaration`) always trying to pull from the Observable, `recordObservable`.

setup to run the source file

```
npm init -y
npm i rxjs@7.4.0 byline
```

source file that does what I want, but in a confusing way

```
// node.js 14
const fs = require('fs');
const pipeline = require('util').promisify(require('stream').pipeline);

const byline = require('byline');
const { Observable } = require('rxjs');
const { take } = require('rxjs/operators');

const sleep = ms => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms));
let recordObservable;

(async () => {
  const inputFilePath = 'temp.csv';

  try {
    const data = 'a,b,c\n' +
      '1,2,3\n' +
      '10,20,30\n' +
      '100,200,300';

    fs.writeFileSync(inputFilePath, data);

    console.log('starting pipeline');
    // remove this line, and the `await pipeline` resolves, but process exits early?
    processAfterDeclaration().catch(console.error);
    
    await pipeline(
      fs.createReadStream(inputFilePath),
      byline.createStream(),
      async function* (sourceStream) {
        console.log('making observable', inputFilePath);

        recordObservable = new Observable(async subscriber => {
          for await (const lineBuffer of sourceStream) {
            subscriber.next(lineBuffer.toString());
          }
          subscriber.complete();
        });

        console.log('made observable', recordObservable);
      }
    );

    console.log('pipeline done', recordObservable);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  } finally {
    fs.unlinkSync(inputFilePath);
  }
})();

async function processAfterDeclaration() {
  while (!recordObservable) {
    await sleep(100);
  }

  console.log('can process');
  await recordObservable
    .pipe(take(2))
    .subscribe(console.log)
}
```

edit: It may be better to just forgo node.js stream.pipeline. I'd think using pipeline is best bc it should be the most efficient and offers backpressuring, but I want to test some things offered by RxJS.

edit2: More reasons to be able to forgo stream.pipeline is that I can still use `pipe` methods and provide any readable stream to the `from` function as an arg. I can then use `subscribe` method to write/append each thing from the observable to my output stream then call `add` on my subscription to add teardown logic, specifically for closing my write stream. I would hope that RxJS `from` would help determine when to close the read stream it's given as input. Finally, I would recommend `await lastValueFrom(myObservable)` or `firstValueFrom` possibly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### RxJS `from` operator

The RxJS `from` operator will turn an async iterator (like node stream) into an observable for you!

I can't run/test on your code, but something in this ballpark should work.

```ts
const fs = require('fs');

const byline = require('byline');
const { from } = require('rxjs');
const { map, take, finalize} = require('rxjs/operators');

const inputFilePath = 'temp.csv';

(async () => {
  const data = 'a,b,c\n' +
    '1,2,3\n' +
    '10,20,30\n' +
    '100,200,300';

  fs.writeFileSync(inputFilePath, data);

  console.log('starting pipeline');

  from(byline(fs.createReadStream(inputFilePath)))
    .pipe(
      map(lineBuffer => lineBuffer.toString()),
      take(2),
      finalize(() => fs.unlinkSync(inputFilePath))
    )
    .subscribe(console.log);
})();
```

#### Your second async function

> I'm not able to explain why the process will exit with code 0 if I don't have another async function (processAfterDeclaration) always trying to pull from the Observable

If you define a function and never call it, that function will never calculate anything.

If you define an observable and never subscribe to it, that observable will never do anything either. That's different from promises which start the moment they're defined. You just need to subscribe to that observable, it doesn't need a separate function though.

This should work the same:

```ts
recordObservable = new Observable(async subscriber => {
  for await (const lineBuffer of sourceStream) {
    subscriber.next(lineBuffer.toString());
  }
  subscriber.complete();
});

recordObservable.pipe(
  take(2)
).subscribe(console.log)
```

Comment: `pipeline` here returns `Promise<void>` though so this doesn't quite work. I find this confusing as node.js doesn't give an example of how the callback for pipeline can contain `err, value`. Seems like it's just the return value of the destination stream / function. A `PassThrough` stream or simple forwarding async iterator doesn't actually have `pipeline` yield a value though. https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v14.x/api/stream.html#stream_stream_pipeline_source_transforms_destination_callback

Answer (score 0):

**The second async function**

> I'm not able to explain why the process will exit with code 0 if I
> don't have another async function (processAfterDeclaration) always
> trying to pull from the Observable

The logic error was that the `await pipeline` would never resolve or reject because the 3rd step in the pipeline would never yield anything because nothing would ever subscribe and pull from the `recordObservable`. It was a deadlock that was written accidentally.